# Force page break at start of table, if too few lines on first page

Tags: html, css

I have some tables with print-reapeating thead and many rows. Sometimes a new table starts at the very bottom line of a page, when printing.
I want to force the table to do a page break, if the space left on the page is less than, say 10 cm.

I tried to put an (invisible) overlapping div before that table:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
<div style="position:abolute; top:0px; width:32px; height:10cm; overflow:visible; page-break-inside: avoid;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<table goes here...>
```

But it's not working. (FF and IE11)

Is there any way to do that? (I'm trying to print a book, and the table is a new chapter).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Chrome.

The code below demonstrates the best method I've found for multi-page table printing. It has the following features:

column headers repeat on each page
if a page break occurs near the top of the table, it will not leave behind an orphaned set of column headers (a problem which isn't limited to just Chrome)
page breaks occur only between rows
no need to worry about paper size or how many rows will fit-- the browser handles everything automatically
cell borders are always fully closed
the above 3 features apply whether or not the table has headers
works in Chrome!
... and the following known limitations:

doesn't support s (tfeet?)
only supports 1  (which is apparently the most you're allowed to have anyway).
only supports top-aligned 
any CSS size values that affect height (including border-width and line-height) must be in px
table cannot (easily) be changed dynamically after the js has run
column widths cannot be set by applying width values to individual table cells; you should either let cell content automatically determine column width, or use s to set specific widths, if needed

Answer (score 0):

I put two tables side by side: the left one (1px) only has a thead with 10cm height, the other contains the contents to print.
That sort of works.
I used float:left; for both tables, so they are side-by-side, but IE11 puts underneath.
Any better idea or an improvment of this approach?